# How to extract a flow chart from points connected with lines?

Tags: qgis, flow

I have some points connected with arrows, like the following example:

[image]

How can I extract a flow chart like the following?

[image]

I tried to use the flowMapper plugin but it seems it is not what I want.

Answer (score 3):

Although it's not a tool within QGIS, I've used Gephi for something similar:

https://gephi.org/

You can use it to represent your data as a number of nodes with relationships in a graph, which seems like what you're after.
I used it to visualise commuting patterns between cities.